# Top part of webpage stays the same

Tags: web, html

I want to create my webpage so that a part at the top that says "Welcome!" and a "main part" below that. When a user clicks on a link in the main part (say, it links to `www.example.com`), the main part should change to the content of `www.example.com`, but the top part should remain the same. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ye olde days, this was done using [frames](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=iframe+html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=dVB&channel=fs&sclient=psy-ab&q=frame+html&oq=frame+html&gs_l=serp.3...42346.42346.0.42575.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3kO0uoLF0ug&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1a830a38825951db&bpcl=35277026&biw=1440&bih=724), but for many reasons, they are going out of use. Try taking a look at [iframes](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=iframe+html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: So, should the top part that says "Welcome!" be an `iframe`, or should the main part that links to `www.example.com` be an `iframe`?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. The part that changes should be in an iframe. Try it out - once you've played with it for a little while, it should be clear how it is best used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the

```
<frameset>
```

tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `<frameset>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Although `<iframe>` works, it will impact your page's searchability (SEO), and setting up the page to scroll properly will be a hassle because the "top" part of the page will be like a page of itself.

Instead of using (i)frames, if you have PHP enabled on the server, you should store the "top" of your webpage as a separate file like "top.php", and in every page, include that with

```
include_once("top.php")
```